# Removing duplicate words from content of pdf

Tags: java, regex

I am parsing PDF with PDFBox, and putting content of pdf in an array list, then I need to remove duplicate words. Here is what I have tried.

```
    List <String> ContentList = new ArrayList<String>();
              List<String> noRepeat = new ArrayList<String>();
              ContentList.add(indexed.content);
              for(String s : ContentList)
              {
                  String result = s.replaceAll("(?i)\\b([a-z]+)\\b(?:\\s+\\1\\b)+", "$1");
                  noRepeat.add(result);
              }
                    System.out.println(noRepeat);
```

I am not using ArrayList below code.

```
String duplicatePattern = "(?i)\\b(\\w+)\\b[\\w\\W]*\\b\\1\\b";
                Pattern pp = Pattern.compile(duplicatePattern);
                Matcher m = pp.matcher(indexed.content);
                while (m.find()) {
                    System.out.println(m.group(1));
                }
```

Small part of the content:

```
Supervised and Unsupervised 
Learning
Agenda
● Introduction
● Supervised Learning
● Unsupervised Learning
What is ML ?
● Field of study that gives computers the 
ability to learn without being explicitly 
programmed
Uniformity of cell size
Uniformity of cell shape
```

The code should only take one `Supervised`, one `Learning`, one `Uniformity` instead of taking every `Supervised`, `Learning`, `Uniformity` etc...

**Update:**

I have coded this and it works.

```
Set<String> indexedContentSet = new HashSet<>(); 

            String[] words = indexed.content.split("\\s+");

            Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(); 
            for(String word : words)
            { 
                if(!set.add(word))
                { 
                    indexedContentSet.add(word); 
                }
            }
```

`set` shows every word, `indexedContentSet` only shows duplicate words. 
Can I also compare `set` and `indexedContentSet` and remove the words which are also values of `indexedContentSet` from `set`?

I have tried this and did not work.

```
if (set.contains(indexedContentSet)) {
                set.remove(indexedContentSet)
            }
```

And how can I remove short words from Set? 
Before program finds duplicate words, I put `indexed.content.replaceAll("\\b\\w{1,4}\\b\\s?", "");` above `Set<String> indexedContentSet = new HashSet<>();` but did not work.

Comment: The simple way to do it, is to cut content on each word and add it to a set. The result set will contains each word in the PDF one time

Comment: Do you want unique elements or you want to remove repeated consecutive element? `set` data structure will be your friend if you need unique elements

Comment: Do you mean  `Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();` ? I am now working on it.

Comment: Yeah for finding all unique elements that will be best

Comment: I will try to do something. If I fail, I will comment here. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @rock321987 Thanks for the suggestion. I tried something. It works, but I have one more question. Could you please take a look?

Comment: @Ali19033 I edited my answer to show how to filter out the words of 4 characters or less. As a side note, this edit should have been a separate question, since rock's comment solved your initial problem.

Comment: @Ali19033 Do you have answer or I need to write as per you say?

Comment: @Aaron's answer is for Java8. I am waiting for him to reply again if he also has an idea for Java7. But I would like to see your answer as well. rock321987

Comment: @Ali19033 then you have to wait for some time

Comment: @Ali19033 any updates..have you seen my code?

Comment: @rock321987 Yes I have. I am analyzing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `Set` as they are designed to contain distinct elements.

```
Set<String> uniqueWords = new HashSet<>();
uniqueWords.addAll(words);
```

To remove short elements, you can filter the set.
With Java 8 :

```
uniqueWords.stream().filter(word -> word.length() > 4).collect(Collectors.toSet());
// returns a new Set that contains the words of uniqueWords of 5 or more characters
```

With Java < 8 :

```
Iterator<String> wordsIt = uniqueWords.iterator();
while (wordsIt.hasNext()) {
  if (wordsIt.next().length() < 5) { wordsIt.remove(); }
}
// at this point the uniqueWords Set only contains words of 5 or more characters
```

Here is a demonstration : https://ideone.com/vRZu1Z

Comment: I should have mentioned that this is Java 8 code. I suppose you're on an earlier version?

Comment: It is java 7. I am working on Play Framework and have no idea how I can upgrade it to 8

Comment: Is it possible to see `wordsIt` as an output? It shows `java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator@5433db18` when I tried `System.out.println(wordsIt.toString());` or `System.out.println(wordsIt);`

Comment: You're not supposed to retrieve the result from the `wordsIt` but from the `uniqueWords` modified set. The iterator is just here to modify the set.

Comment: @Ali19033 I had forgotten to actually use the iterator to iterate the set, please see my updated answer.

Comment: I was about to create an ideone link to show where mistake was. Is it also possible to make every word inside `Set` lowercase? I wrote `wordsIt.next().toLowerCase();` right above `if` statement which is inside `while`, it did not work.

Comment: Yes, it's possible ; however, it's outside of the scope of this question. Please accept this answer if it solved your original problem and open another question for your current one.

Comment: Okay, Thanks again. I will open a topic about it if I cannot solve it.

Comment: I would suggest populating an other set with the lowercase version of each word long enough

Answer (score 1):

It took some time because I have to recreate everything

```
Set<String> indexedContentSet = new HashSet<>(); //It contains only the words that are repeated twice or more than that
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(); //This contains all unique words

String tmp; //This variable reads line from user input

for (int i = 0;i < 12;i++) { //There are 12 lines for input
    tmp = x.nextLine();  //Read each line
    String arr[] = tmp.split("\\s+"); //Split on the basis of space

    for (String y: arr) { //For each word in the line do the following

        if (y.length() > 3) { //If the length of word is more than 3, then only include it in set

            if (set.contains(y)) {  //If unique word set already contains that element, then its a duplicate..So add it to indexedContentSet
                indexedContentSet.add(y); //If you want to add only in lowercase, you can use indexedContentSet.add(y.toLowerCase());
            }

            set.add(y); //Add all the words to set(which will finally be unique)..Also if you want to add only in lowercase, you can use set.add(y.toLowerCase());
        }   
     }
    }
```

[**Ideone Demo**](http://ideone.com/rZQXX8)

Comment: This is also a nice and easy to understand. You did not use Iterator. I think I have to search deeper for Iterator.  I now am trying to make more specialize, like removing numbers, some symbolic characters($, (, !, @, .).  `[^\\p{L}\\p{Z}]` this regex matches everything that is not a letter in any language and not a separator (whitespace, linebreak etc.). Should l write it in `.split()`? `.split("[^\\p{L}\\p{Z}]\\s+");`  as I know, I should also define replacement when I use single line regex. `.replaceAll(regex, replacement);` `.split()` does not have second parameter for replacement.

Comment: @Ali19033 well you can use it as `[^\\p{L}\\p{Z}]\\s]` for splitting, but first of all I will strongly recommend you to read about `regex` and then proceed..don't be in a rush..take your time and then proceed

Comment: Well, that is the main problem. I sometimes do not know what I am doing, but what I do is working, but I do not know what I am doing. It is so complicated... 
Thank you for your help. I now have some experience about `HashSet`.

Comment: @Ali19033 I can understand..been there, done that..keep calm